# How can I install Fedora (with working WIFI) onto macbook pro?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, installation, fedora

How can I install Fedora onto macbook pro(early 2011)?

I would like for WIFI to work on Fedora after the install.

This will need to be a completely offline install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having experience a similar situation booting an early 2008 aluminum macbook with 10.11.6 (El Capitan) using an external USB drive (Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1) your question isn't clear. Wifi continues to work after reboot for which operating system? I had to get MacOS to reload it's firmware using safe boot. For  Linux see [systemd: automate modprobe command at boot time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71064/systemd-automate-modprobe-command-at-boot-time) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange substituting b43 as the target.

Comment: It's unclear if you are having a problem, or if you are trying to post step-instructions to perform this process. If the former, could you please edit your question to clarify the actual question? If the latter, a better way to do this would be to post a QUESTION first, and then this ANSWER as an answer, and then mark it as such when allowed, making it clear what question this is in answer to.

Comment: It looks like OP posted a question "How to install Fedora on Macbook year X version Y" but should put the solution into an Answer instead of editing the question.  That's a very useful list for the next time someone wants to do the same thing!  Be sure to specify the Fedora version, MacBook year and model, and what each other software (with version) that the process needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Offline install of Fedora 28 onto Macbook 2011:

1. Important: download the firmware/driver to a usb/zip drive or burn it to dvd. It is the firmware/driver you will need to install for Linux to run the broadcom wifi card inside the macbook: http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2. Also, create a bootable image of High Sierra on a usb drive so you can go back to macos if you would like to. Download the High Sierra installer app from the apple store and create a bootable usb drive from it: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-usb-installer-for-macos-high-sierra/
2. Download Fedora 28 Live iso.
3. Use Etcher.io to create a Fedora bootable USB drive that a Macbook can boot Fedora from.
4. Insert the Fedora bootable USB drive and start Macbook while pressing the option key until you see the apple logo appear.
5. When the boot options appear select EFI boot and then "start Fedora".
6. Follow the options to install Fedora to hard disk.
7. Restart Fedora.
8. Insert the media where you stored the broadcom firmware/driver.
9. `cd /`
10. `tar xjf /path-to-broadcom-driver/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz`
11. Extract and install the broadcom firmware/driver:
    `sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o`
12. Load the firmware with the following command: `modprobe b43`

Comment: THANK YOU! Seriously.  Been holding off installing Qubes OS on my macook for years until you posted this!